# TypeError: connection.execute is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Why do I get this error when I call my API from postman?

```
http://localhost:4000/api/employees/employees1
```

This is my error looks like.

```
TypeError: connection.execute is not a function
    at getQuestion1 (C:\Users\ej\OneDrive\Desktop\OJT\sdd\api\controllers\employee\part_1_question.js:28:48)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ej\OneDrive\Desktop\OJT\sdd\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\ej\OneDrive\Desktop\OJT\sdd\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\ej\OneDrive\Desktop\OJT\sdd\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ej\OneDrive\Desktop\OJT\sdd\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\ej\OneDrive\Desktop\OJT\sdd\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\ej\OneDrive\Desktop\OJT\sdd\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\ej\OneDrive\Desktop\OJT\sdd\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\ej\OneDrive\Desktop\OJT\sdd\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
    at router (C:\Users\ej\OneDrive\Desktop\OJT\sdd\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

that is my end point I used, and this is my backend looks like.

Here is my database wherein I export it.

Db.js

const mysql2 = require('mysql2/promise');

```
const connection = mysql2.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'admin',
  database: 'sdd_crud',
});

module.exports = connection;
```

After that I call it to my Part_Js

Part_1.js

```
const connection = require('../../DB/db.js');

 const getQuestion1 = async (req,res) =>{
    const query = "SELECT * FROM studentsquestionpart1"

    try {
        const [rows, field] = await connection.execute(query)
        res.status(200).json(rows)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json(error)
    }
}
module.exports = {getQuestion1 }
```

This is my router.js, I can call it but gave me an error

```
router.js

router.get('/employees1/', getQuestion1)
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const employeeQuestion = require('./routes/employee/part_1_question.js');

const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    res.send("Hello World")
})

app.use('/api/employees', employeeQuestion)



app.listen(4000, () =>{
    console.log(`Website is running at port http://localhost:${4000}`)
})
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: have you tried logging connection in db.js to see if it is undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Notice the error message (`connection.execute is not a function`), which typically means "you're calling something that doesn't exist".
2. Think why it doesn't exist, look where `connection` is coming from and why would it not have the `execute` method on it.
3. See that `connection = require('../../DB/db.js')`, so check what's the default export from `db.js`
4. See that the default export is the result of `mysql2.createConnection()`, where `mysql2` is imported from `mysql2/promise`.
5. Check `mysql2` [documentation](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-promise-wrapper) and see this example:

   ```
   // get the client
   const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
   // create the connection
   const connection = await mysql.createConnection({host:'localhost', user: 'root', database: 'test'});
   ```
6. Notice that `createConnection` returns a Promise, since it's being `await`ed.
7. Promises don't have `execute` method, so that's why you're getting this error. You have to either `await` the promise, or use `.then` to get the thing inside the Promise. And that thing has the `execute` method.

---

Looking at your code,

```
const [rows, field] = await connection.execute(query)
```

You're awaiting the result of `connection.execute`, but the problem is (as I've revealed through my reasoning above) that `connection` is itself a `Promise`.

So any of these should fix the problem:

```
const conn = await connection;
const [rows, field] = await conn.execute(query);
// or
const [rows, field] = await (await connection).execute(query);
// or
const [rows, field] = await connection.then(establishedConnection => establishedConnection.execute(query));
```